# Program strangely returning to the top of the loop

Tags: c, loops, switch-statement

I would like to preface this question by saying I'm new to C and therefore terrible at it, so I apologize in advance for any blatant errors or bad style. Also, I'm not sure how to introduce the problem before showing you my code, so here it is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


int main()
{

    int MAX_INPUT_SIZE = 200;
    volatile int running = 1;
    while (running)
    {

        char input[MAX_INPUT_SIZE];
        char *tokens[100];
        const char *cmds[] = { "wait", "pwd", "cd", "exit" };
        char *cmdargs[100];

        printf("shell> ");
        fgets(input, MAX_INPUT_SIZE, stdin);

        // remove newline character at end
        int nl = strlen(input) - 1;
        if (input[nl] == '\n')
        {
            input[nl] = '\0';
        }

        // tokenize input string, put each token into an array
        char *space;
        space = strtok(input, " ");
        tokens[0] = space;

        int i = 1;
        while (space != NULL)
        {
            space = strtok(NULL, " ");
            tokens[i] = space;
            ++i;
        }

        // copy tokens after first one into string
        int noargscheck;
        if (tokens[1] != NULL)
        {
            noargscheck = 0;
            strcpy((char *)cmdargs, tokens[1]);
            for (i = 2; tokens[i] != NULL; i++)
            {
                strcat((char *)cmdargs, " ");
                strcat((char *)cmdargs, tokens[i]);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            noargscheck = 1;
        }

        // compare tokens[0] to list of internal commands
        int isInternal = -1;
        for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            if (strcmp(tokens[0], cmds[i]) == 0)
            {
                isInternal = i;
            }
        }


        // internal commands
        char wd[200];
        if (isInternal != -1)
        {
            switch (isInternal)
            {
            case 0:
                // wait
                break;
            case 1:
                // pwd
                if (getcwd(wd, sizeof(wd)) == NULL)
                {
                    perror("getcwd() error!");
                }
                else
                {
                    printf("%s\n", wd);
                }
                break;
            case 2:
                // cd
                if (noargscheck)
                {
                    chdir("/home");
                }
                else if (chdir((const char *)cmdargs) != 0)
                {
                    perror("cd failed");
                }
                break;
            case 3:
                // exit
                exit(1);
                break;
            }
        }

        else
        {
            // external commands

            pid_t child_pid;
            switch (child_pid = fork())
            {
            case -1:
                perror("Fork failed");
                return 1;
            case 0:
                // child
                printf("\nHERE\n"); // for debugging
                execvp(tokens[0], cmdargs);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I run this code with the input `echo hello world`, the program successfully enters the `case 0` case in the second switch statement that starts with `switch (child_pid=fork())` but the output, which is unexpected, is as follows:

OUTPUT: (including one line that shows my input at the prompt)

`shell> echo hello world` (my input)

`shell>` (this is the part I don't understand)

`HERE`

`shell>` (the program now waits here at the prompt for the next user input)

I cannot figure out why the extra `shell>` prompt is printing. Can anybody see the problem?

EDIT: fixed the first parameter of execvp. Changed from `"echo"` (which was there because I'm silly) to `tokens[0]`.

Comment: Can you explain why you *don't* expect to see it? In other words, describe how you think your code should not be resulting in this behavior.

Comment: I don't want the extra `shell> ` printed, meaning the one in between the first `shell> ` and `HERE`. Dan has pointed out below that the problem is that my child process is reporting an error from execvp, which I am not checking, and then returning to the top of the loop.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you fork, you now have two processes at that point. Your child will print the `HERE` message and then call `execvp`. You do not check the return value of `execvp` and so it may be returning an error. `cmdargs` should be a vector - that is, a null-pointer-terminated array of string pointers. Instead, you are passing `execvp` a string. In other words, it expects a `char* []`, which is what `cmdargs` is, however you have previously treated `cmdargs` incorrectly.

For example, you say `strcpy((char*)cmdargs, tokens[1]);`. This places a string at `*cmdargs`. A string is an array of zero or more non-zero characters followed by an ascii `NUL` which is 8 bits wide:

```
char* cmdargs[] is a double pointer
you treat cmdargs as a single pointer and feed it to strcpy
cmdargs points to: 'H' 'e' 'l' 'l' 'o' '\0'
```

However, this is not what execvp wants. Execvp wants a vector, which looks somewhat more like this:

```
char* cmdargs[] is a double pointer
cmdargs[0] is a single pointer
cmdargs[0] points to: 'H' 'e' 'l' 'l' 'o' '\0'
cmdargs[1] points to: 'w' 'o' 'r' 'l' 'd' '\0'
cmdargs[2] is a null pointer, indicating that it is the end of the vector
```

Therefore, execvp is unable to find the end of the vector and fails, returning `-1`. You do not test for this, so the child process continues back to the top of the loop, as does the parent, and both processes print `shell>`.

EDIT: By the way, the FIRST string in the `argv` vector SHOULD be the name of the file being executed - in this case, `echo`, and then the second and third strings should be the first and second 'arguments' - here `hello` and `world`. This is the argv vector fed to the program you call, and by convention the first element in that vector is the name of the called program. If you ignore that convention, `echo` will get terribly confused.

Comment: I see. Pointers have always been the death of me. How would I go about fixing `cmdargs` to send `execvp` the correct parameters?

Answer (score 0):

cmdargs is defined as an array of 100 string-pointers, but you seem to use it as one 100-byte buffer for a single string. I also don't get why you handle token[1] specially. Only token[0] is special, that's the command, all the others are arguments. Processing the arguments should be a loop of

```
while (cmdargs[i++] = strtok(NULL, " "))
```

and then the closing NULL pointer in cmdargs for execvp():

```
cmdargs[i] = NULL;
```

This being a shell, you also forgot to wait for child processes. You will prompt the user for input before the last child process has finished. The final switch-case should look line this:

```
pid_t child_pid;
switch (child_pid = fork())
{
case -1:
    perror("Fork failed");
    return 1;
case 0:
    // child
    printf("\nHERE\n"); // for debugging
    execvp(tokens[0], cmdargs);
    perror("Exec failed");
    exit(1);
default:
    // parent
    int status;
    wait(&status);
    break;
}
```

Comment: execvp() does not return normally, as your whole child process starts to run a new progam. If it does return, it's an error, e.g. the program to execute was not found, so it's an error message. The child process must exit too.

Comment: Won't that `perror` print every time though? Even if execvp worked?

Comment: You are confusing `system()` with `execvp()`. `system()` creates a child process that executes the specified program. In case of `execvp()`, you've already created the child process with `fork()`, and this same child process throws away your program, and starts executing the specified program. It cannot return to your program, as that was thrown away already.

Comment: Cool! The fork/exec syscalls are tricky to understand first, but when you grok it, it's quite beautiful. :-) Remember: fork() returns twice, and execvp() does not return at all.